# How to use the Spring OAuth2 client to retrieve an access token only?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, access-token

I've been trying to figure out how to use spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client package to retrieve an oAuth token from an OpenID server.

I can configure the application.yml file with the appropriate settings, and see that the `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` and `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` beans are created properly.

I'm even able to create a ClientManager, although not entirely sure why this isn't done automatically by SpringBoot.  But then, frankly, I am stumped as to how to get an OAuth2Client from the manager.

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          auth0:
            client-id: MgqYHnr4p3wed9qKdzRu9G
            client-secret: some_secret_code
        provider:
          auth0:
            issuer-uri: https://dev-5cjo8.eu.auth0.com/
```

```
    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                         final ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

I'm a bit perplexed as to what the next step would be.  I am looking to use `grant_type: client_credentials` and exchange the clientId/secret that are in the application.yml file for an AccessToken, but not sure how to accomplish this.

It would be fairly straightforward to send a request to the `token_endpoint` using a RestTemplate and parsing the response, but I figure there must be a way to accomplish this using the OAuth2 lib.

How do I use the clientManager to get a client to authenticate using the token endpoint?  Keep in mind that I am not looking to build a web-app, or retrieve a specific resource - I am just looking for the  access token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Countless hours of investigating later, I discovered that the  `DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` is intended to be used within a request context. (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8444#issuecomment-621567261)

Accordingly, modifying the ClientManager bean to be defined as:

```
    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(final ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
                                                                         final ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, clientService);

        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
```

allows for use of the client as follows:

```
    public String getAccessToken(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager manager){
        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest req = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("auth0").principal("N/A").build();
        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = manager.authorize(req).block();
        return client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. create config**

- in application.yml (for application.properties write it correspondingly)

  ```
   spring:
     security:
       oauth2:
         client:
           registration:
             YOUR_REGISTARTION_ID>:
               client-id: 
               client-secret: 
               authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
               redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/authorized/yourendpoint"
               scope: api://YOUR-CLIENT-ID/.default
           provider:
             YOUR_REGISTARTION_ID:
               authorization-uri: https://XYZ_AUTHORITY/YOUR-CLIENT-ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
               token-uri: https://XYZ_AUTHORITY/YOUR-CLIENT-ID/oauth2/v2.0/token
  ```

- fill the configuration corresping to your authority and app credentials

**2. create config class**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder().clientCredentials().build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }
}
```

**3. request JWT**

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizeRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class OAuth2TokenRequester {
    
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager;

    public OAuth2TokenRequester(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager) {
        this.authorizedClientManager = oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param clientRegistrationId as configured in application.yml (spring.security.oauth.client.registration.*)
     * @param principal (e.g. "N/A")
     * @return OAuth2AuthorizedClient which can be asked for access and refresh tokens
     */
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorize(String clientRegistrationId, String principal) {
        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest req = Auth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId).principal(principal).build();
        return authorizedClientManager.authorize(req);
    }

    public String requestAccessToken() {
        String jwt = authorize("YOUR_REGISTARTION_ID", "N/A").getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
}
```